# Why is the reputation of the last user to interact with a question shown on the Home page?

Tags: support, questions, users

I just noticed that front page now shows reputation on the "modified [time] ago [name] [rating]" line:

[image: screenshot of workplace front page]

When was this rolled out? What is the reasoning behind that change?

Comment: Hmm. Did this not used to be there or is this a slimmer version of the normal page which includes avatars and rep+badges? I haven't used the home page in years so I have no idea... :) Appears to be the same on main meta though.

Comment: Looking at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343856/are-users-reputation-scores-on-the-home-page-supposed-to-stand-out-that-much-no) that talked about a slight change to the way reputation is drawn, the fact that reputation is shown would have to be over a year old. Unless we were rocking an old CSS of course.

Comment: @Lilienthal i might have been just blinded to the right side of the screen for years.

Answer (score 6):

This has been the current situation for as long as <s>I can remember. (But I'm here for only five years.)</s> the site exists; see this screenshot taken on Stack Overflow *over 10 years ago*:

[image]
([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39782/295232))

Is this feature useful? Well, if you see a question modified by a high-reputation user like Joe, you can be sure there's nothing unusual about it. If you see a question asked/answered/modified by a 1 rep user, chances are they're not familiar with The Workplace rules and their action needs some extra scrutiny.

Comment: Yes, a question with a LOT of views (so it was probably posted long ago) freshly answered by a 1-rep user is almost always spam or question-disguised-as-answer. The pattern is easy to spot.